# ActiveRecord Dynamic :has_many foreign_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, has-many

I have 3 models, Person, Player and Injury.

Player = `#<Player id: 9999, name: "Bob the player", person_key: "some-unique-key">`

Person = `#<Person id: 1234, person_key: "some-unique-key">`

Injury = `#<Injury id: 8374, injury: "Hurt", person_id: 1234>`

---

Player - `has_one :person, :foreign_key => :person_key, :primary_key => :person_key`

Person - `has_one :player, :foreign_key => :person_key, :primary_key => :person_key`

Injury - `belongs_to :person`

---

I primarily work with Player and I need to be able to have a has_many relationship from Player to injuries

Player.injury needs to do something akin to;

`Player - has_many :injuries, :foreign_key => :person_id, :primary_key => { self.person.id }`

I realize that you can't do `self.person.id` there, but that's the relation I need.  (I didn't design this relationship, it's just what I have to work with..)

Thoughts?

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why do you have a separate `person_key` field? It seems like you're using it to form the relationship between `Player` and `Person`, but that might be better served by a `has_one` and `belongs_to` instead through the usual primary key - foreign key relationship, non?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add folowing relations:

```
Person - has_many :injuries
Player - has_many :injuries, through: :person
```

Comment: Gah! I swear I tried that and it didn't work.. works fine. hah! Thanks.